# Export data into word documents

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis

My boss has a kindle and likes to save a lot of stuff to his clippings.  Currently I'm going through and cutting out each clipping and pasting it into a seperate word document with the title of the article.  I have managed to import the txt file into sql server and have generated an SSIS package to clean up the data and to provide me with what I want.  The part that I'm having difficulty with is being able to take each article and generate a word document.  Is there a way to do this with SQL Server and Intergration Services?

edit- 
Definition of the data that I have:

```
create table dbo.Articles
(
PK_ID int identity(1,1),
Title nvarchar(50),
Article nvarchar(max)
)
```

Comment: I'm curious are you doing this for your benefit or your bosses? 

Have you thought of just using PowerShell? If you are just wanting to break up the text file into Word documents that can be done with PowerShell without much fuss.

Comment: @Shawn Melton, both.  He want's it in a readable format on the computer and I don't want to spend 2 hours cutting his clippings into 60 word documents.  I'm not familiar with powershell at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL Server and SSIS, you should also have Reporting Services.

This can generate [Word documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239307.aspx#ExportFormats). This can be interactive, or you can use [URL access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155362.aspx), or [SOAP calls](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153968.aspx) to get at data.

May not be ideal, but it takes away the need to try and write Word documents via scripting or code: you just need some way to invoke what MS provide